# Bootstrap .btn-group mixin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have imported less files of Twitter Bootstrap into my .less file.
I have a code as following:

```
.profile-controls {
    .btn-group;
    .pull-right;

    & > button {
      .btn;
      .btn-default;
    }
}
```

but buttons are not styled, nor grouped. When I hard-code .btn, .btn-default to buttons and .btn-group to parent div, everything works fine, but I want to avoid this and declare everything in CSS as it seems to be the correct way.

Comment: Could you provide your HTML-structure?

Comment: I have the same issue. I can apply other styles via my less, so I know the selectors are valid, but the `.btn-group` mixin doesn't seem to work.